# Single statement consuming ~1000 ms to execute - Is it obvious?

Tags: php, performance, drupal-7

rerouted from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83846/single-statement-consuming-1000-ms-to-execute-is-it-obvious)

The `concat.=$concat .= $ref_wrapper->$er_field_mac_id->nid->value();` line is consuming more time to execute. Is it obvious or is there some thing else that might cause this behaviour.

What am I doing?
1.Iterate field collection item as it is a multi value field
2.Iterate though field inside field_collection item to get field whose machine name ends with **_list_er** (this is a entity reference field)
3.Once machine name found break and do not enter second loop again
4 Continue with outer loop and set the $concat variable

Why loop to get machine name?
I do not want it hardcoded like field_item_list_er, because same snippet should be applied to different fields that ends tith _list_er. Ex. field_tv_list_er, field_favteam_list_er.

```
timer_start('get_loop_time');
foreach ($wrapper->$list_mac_id->getIterator() as $delta => $ref_wrapper) {
    if (!isset($er_field_mac_id)) {
        foreach ($ref_wrapper->getIterator() as $in_fci) {
            $in_fci = $in_fci->info();
            if (is_array($in_fci)) {
                if (is_array($in_fci) && isset($in_fci['type']) && $in_fci['type'] == 'node' && preg_match(
                        "/_list_er\z/i",
                        $in_fci['name']
                    )
                ) {
                    $er_field_mac_id = $in_fci['name'];
                    break 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //following statement consuming from ~600ms to ~750ms for each iteration(currently only 2)
    timer_start('get_single_time');
    $concat .= $ref_wrapper->$er_field_mac_id->nid->value();
    dpm(timer_read('get_single_time'));
}
//so then total is from ~1200ms to ~1400 ms  (includes for loop)
dpm(timer_read('get_loop_time'));
```

**update: apologies :( for lack of info,now details are updated.One more thing there are > 10000 node are present to which entityreference field is referenced.**

**update2:while seaching for the solution I found the [link](http://audiblecode.com/blog/programmatically-create-and-update-field-collection-item-node-entity-api) about accessing field_collection_item and further splitted the statement like below**

```
// Load that field collection item
$field_collection_item_value = $ref_wrapper->value();

// Wrap it with Entity API
$collection = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $ref_wrapper);

$val = $collection->{$er_field_mac_id}->value()->nid;
```

From above code it is found that statement `$field_collection_item_value = $ref_wrapper->value();` is consuming more time around 600ms for each iteration, where $ref_wrapper is a field collection item. Is it a problem with the field collection item for taking so much  of time for loading single field value(inside field_collection_item two fields are there one is entityreference and another is textfield)

Comment: You cannot know that this LAST statement consumes all the time because you are not measuring it explicitly. How did you find it out? And whatever your code does in the call to `value()` is important. Without code nobody can answer besides "Remove the call to `sleep()`".

Comment: 1000 ms = 1 sec. isn't it?

Comment: Assuming you're right, is it using 1,000 ms each iteration, or in total? How many iterations are there in the loop? How big is `$concat`, maybe you're using lots of time re-allocating a huge string? What does the `value()` function do, maybe it's using lots of time?

Comment: @itachi please see update made above. `value()` is for getting node id of entityreferenced node

Comment: @Barmar $concat will only concatination of node ids like 12223343( where 1222 3343 are two node nids)

Comment: Try splitting that assignment into `$val = $ref_wrapper->$er_field_mac_id->nid->value(); $concat .= $val;` and put timers around each of them, to see which is really using the time.

Comment: `timer_read()` doesn't stop the timer, so when you print it in later iterations, I think it's including the time spent in the upper loop. You should call `timer_stop('get_single_time').

Comment: @Barmar 1. when code is splitted into `$va=$ref_wrapper->$er_field_mac_id->nid->value();` = ~ 580ms and 630ms for two iteration. and `$concat.=$val;` = 0.02ms for both iteration.  
2. I think you are mistaken about timer_stop as it is including spent time not timer_read() as you mentioned.

Comment: So the problem is clearly in `value()`, you need to examine that method to see why it's so slow.

Comment: strangely timer_stop() is showing 580ms and 1120ms(may be including previous one).I replaced `$er_field_mac_id` with hardcoded machine name of ER field then also same behoviour :(. I will check other alternative for value() and update later.

Comment: @Barmar I splitted the code (see updates above), I think it is related to field collection item `$field_collection_item_value = $ref_wrapper->value();`.I don't know if it is possible to debug what exactly is happening inside that statement, maybe profiling or something similar.